# Python: Is there any Pythonic way that allows searching through SQL queries in a directory? How to find the indicated query among a bunch of files?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, information-retrieval

I'm not sure this is the best way to find the **desired query**. Possibly there is a *Python* library that allows you to search a file more intelligently and bring the most **relevant results**.
I am currently using the following code:

```
import re
from pathlib import Path #To find all the path to the results in the folder.
import os
from functools import reduce



def find_query(pattern):
    path_queries = []
    
    for filename in Path(r'\\path/where/the/queries/are/').rglob('*.sql'):
        path_queries.append(filename.__str__())
        
    for path in path_queries:
        if os.path.exists(path):
            conds = [(i.lower() in str(path).lower()) for i in pattern]
            cond = reduce(lambda a, b: a and b, conds, True) # similar to foldl
            if  cond:
                print(path)
            try:
                with open(path, encoding="Latin") as file:
                    content = file.read()
                    conds = [(re.search(i, content, re.I)) for i in pattern]
                    cond = reduce(lambda a, b: a and b, conds, True) # similar to foldl
                    if cond:
                        print(path)
            except:
                print("Error with file: ", path)
        else:
            print('The path: ', path, ' is wrong!')
            
            
find_query([r"max\(case"])#, r'another-keyword-of-interest'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
files_path = [os.path.join(path, file) for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(yourPath) for file in files if file.split(".")[-1] == "sql"]
```

This will return all the `.sql` files from `yourPath`
`os.walk()` returns the path to each file/folder, all folders and all files from the location
`for file in files if file.split(".")[-1] == "sql"` checks all files and returns only those that have `.sql` extenstion
`os.path.join(path, file)` will build a correct full path to those files

The only way to find all `sql` files is to check each file if it's an `sql` one. You can improve it if you know some rules about the structure (for example, if a folder contains a `sql` file, all are `sql` files, or if a folder contains a `non-sql` file, then for sure there are no `sql` files)